# Splunk like search feature in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, solr

I have an application which is have 300+ million records. I would like to implement splunk the search mechanism to filter out the records from the DB.

i.e the user can write a query in normal English and that would be converted to the SQL query and retrieve the data for the user.

Is there any tool/gems available for that? any other suggestion would be great.

I have some experience with solr.

thx.

Comment: Although I haven't used it, the most recent release of Solr has SQL-like functionality.  I am not aware of anything that does the translation from normal English to the SQL, but if something like that exists for Ruby - perhaps there's a way to connect the output (the SQL) to Solr.  See this for some info on the Solr SQL ability...  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parallel+SQL+Interface

Comment: have you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet. Will update if any.